# Not intersecting chords on circle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, chord-diagram

I'm trying to implement the task. We have 2*n points on circle. So we can create n chords between them. Print all ways to draw n not intersecting chords.

For example: if n = 6. We can draw (1->2 3->4 5->6), (1->4, 2->3, 5->6), (1->6, 2->3, 4->5), (1->6, 2->5, 3->4)

I've developed a recursive algorithms by creating a chord from 1-> 2, 4, 6 and generating answers for 2 remaining intervals. But I know there is more efficient non-recursive way. May be by implementing NextSeq function.

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPD: I do cache intermediate results, but what I really want is to find GenerateNextSeq() function, which can generate next sequence by previous and so generate all such combinations

This is my code by the way

```
struct SimpleHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& p) const {
        return p.first ^ p.second;
    }
};

struct Chord {
    int p1, p2;
    Chord(int x, int y) : p1(x), p2(y) {};
};

void MergeResults(const vector<vector<Chord>>& res1, const vector<vector<Chord>>& res2, vector<vector<Chord>>& res) {
    res.clear();
    if (res2.empty()) {
        res = res1;
        return;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < res1.size(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < res2.size(); k++) {
            vector<Chord> cur;

            for (int j = 0; j < res1[i].size(); j++) {
                cur.push_back(res1[i][j]);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < res2[k].size(); j++) {
                cur.push_back(res2[k][j]);
            }
            res.emplace_back(cur);

        }

    }
}

int rec = 0;
int cached = 0;

void allChordsH(vector<vector<Chord>>& res, int st, int end, unordered_map<pair<int, int>, vector<vector<Chord>>, SimpleHash>& cach) {
    if (st >= end)
        return;

    rec++;

    if (cach.count( {st, end} )) {
        cached++;
        res = cach[{st, end}];
        return;
    }

    vector<vector<Chord>> res1, res2, res3, curRes;
    for (int i = st+1; i <=end; i += 2) {
        res1 = {{Chord(st, i)}};
        allChordsH(res2, st+1, i-1, cach);
        allChordsH(res3, i+1, end, cach);


        MergeResults(res1, res2, curRes);
        MergeResults(curRes, res3, res1);

        for (auto i = 0; i < res1.size(); i++) {
            res.push_back(res1[i]);
        }

        cach[{st, end}] = res1;

        res1.clear(); res2.clear(); res3.clear(); curRes.clear();
    }
}

void allChords(vector<vector<Chord>>& res, int n) {
    res.clear();

    unordered_map<pair<int, int>, vector<vector<Chord>>, SimpleHash> cach; // intrval => result

    allChordsH(res, 1, n, cach);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean n=3 in your example?

Comment: what do you mean by more efficient? Recursive way like this is indeed efficient as it only prints and enters iff there is a possible way.

Comment: I mean we need to merge all 3 results from intervals made by creating the first chord. And that is why we need to by them a lot of time. While generating new sequence from previous avoid this

Comment: Recursive algo will be like, you take point(1) [meaning the first point in the interval] and connect it to any point only if resulting intervals have even number of points. Then continue and when you reach a possible set, print it. And continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming. That is, cache partial results.

Basically, start from 1 chord, compute all answers and add them to cache.
Then take 2 chords, compute all answers using the cache whenever you can.
Etc.

Recursive way is O(n!) (at least n!, I'm bad with complexity calculation).

This way is n/2-1 operations for each step and n steps, therefore O(n^2), which is much better. However, this solution depends on memory, as it has to hold all the combinations in the cache. 15 chords easily uses 1GB of memory (Java solution).

---

**Example solution:**
https://ideone.com/g81zP9

Completes 12 chord computation in ~306ms. 
Given 1GB of RAM it computes 15 chords in ~8sec.

Cache is saved in specific format to optimize performance: number saved in array means how much further is the link. For example [1,0,3,1,0,0] means:

```
1  0  3  1  0  0
|--|  |  |--|  |
      |--------|
```

You can transform it in a separate step to whatever format you want.

Comment: Why do you say recursive one is O(n!)? Since he needs all possible combinations, recursive one has complexity of just that order, number  of combinations possible.

Comment: Not really, as you are doing unneeded calculations to produce same result. For example, consider a task "print numbers from a to b, n times". One solution would be to do a nested for loop, this would result in O((b-a)*n) complexity. Second one, would generate a list [a..b] once, and then print it n times in other loop. This would be O((b-a) + n) complexity.

Comment: Why would we be doing unneeded calculations? And if the final result has order (n!) output sets, you cannot do better than (n!) in any case.

Comment: Can you print all permutations of a word in any way less than (n!) complexity? No, because that is the number of results you need to print.

Comment: That's the problem here. Final result does not have n! output sets, but you will do n! calculations in this case. For example, for n=3 (6 points), here are your operations: 1. AA0000. 2. AABB00. 3. AABBCC (result). 4. A00A00. 5. ABBA00. 6. ABBACC (result). 7. A0000A. 8. ABB00A. 9. ABBCCA (result). Therefore - you've got 3 results in 9 operations.

Comment: Added example solution.